# Need preview windows on mobile platform

Tags: feature-request, editing, markdown-preview, mobile-web

Maybe this is a duplicate of some other questions, but why do we not have preview windows like another exchange site where I post answers (or if we do have them, how to access them)?

Such windows would be immensely helpful eliminating edits for typographical errors or mathematical expressions that don't display as expected.  These things are hard to see when I work from a cellphone, and I welcome a chance to view answers so I can catch them before posting.

Comment: It's there, under each post. Did you click "hide preview" by any chance? Look for "show preview" then.

Comment: I never see that, is it missing from the mobile platform?

Comment: Do you mean the mobile version of the website, or the mobile application?

Comment: Mobile version of the website.

Comment: Easy solution: stop using it.

Comment: Nice response :-( .

Comment: I'm serious. In the past [nearly] six years I've been using this website, I've also used it from my various smartphones. It was always the first thing I did, switch to the full site.

Comment: From the phone.  Oh now I see.

Answer (score 1):

I found that preview is available on the full site, which can be accessed from a mobile device by tapping "full site" link in the footer.

---

This is a test to see if the full site works ...

$2+2=4$

Actually this is cool!  Thanks, I'll remember to switch sites ftom now on.  Thanks everyone!

---

Comment: See? I told you. :-)

Comment: I edited your answer so that it can be more useful as a reference for others.